# symfony 4 security.yaml is missing

Tags: symfony4

I recently start a project in symfony 4, so i wanna make a login page, I actually follow all the security process in there => https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#create-user-class

But all this tutorial is based on the security.yaml file who doesn't exist in my project and when i add it manually i'have got an error and my app is kind of freeze ... so what i'm supposed to do ?

I have to precise i download the "skeleton" architecture .

Thx for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try the following cmd :

```
composer remove security-bundle
composer require security-bundle
```

Should work now ;)

Thanks !
Good luck !